# Why does writing to my log file fail in the background thread

Tags: c, multithreading, visual-studio

My Windows app is written in C. The main thread uses CreateThread to run a function in another thread.

The problem is that if the main thread called the below function before calling CreateThread, calls to the function from the second thread fail to write messages to the file. If the second thread passes a different file name, then it works. Something seems to be blocking the background threads from opening the file.

```
void WINAPI WriteToLogFile(LPSTR lpszLogfile, LPSTR lpszMsg)
{
   HANDLE hFile;
   DWORD dwWritten = 0;
   char szMsgText[MAX_PATH];

   time_t now = time(0);
   memset(szMsgText, 0x00, sizeof(szMsgText));
   strftime(szMsgText, 100, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S - ", localtime(&now));

   hFile = CreateFile(lpszLogfile,
               FILE_APPEND_DATA, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL,
               OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

   WriteFile(hFile, szMsgText, (DWORD)strlen(szMsgText), &dwWritten, 0);
   WriteFile(hFile, lpszMsg, (DWORD)strlen(lpszMsg), &dwWritten, 0);
   WriteFile(hFile, "\r\n", 2, &dwWritten, 0);

   CloseHandle(hFile);
}
```

Comment: Do you have two threads trying to write to the file at the same time?  You're not checking the result of `CreateFile` to see if you actually open the file.

Comment: where/.what is the code that fails?  how are the threads created?

Comment: The two threads are not calling the function at the same time. The app is an IIS ISAPI Extension. I changed the code to below and it still has the problem:

Comment: hFile = CreateFile(lpszLogfile,
               FILE_GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL,
               OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
   if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
      WriteFile(hFile, szMsgText, (DWORD)strlen(szMsgText), &dwWritten, 0);
      WriteFile(hFile, lpszMsg, (DWORD)strlen(lpszMsg), &dwWritten, 0);
      WriteFile(hFile, "\r\n", 2, &dwWritten, 0);
      CloseHandle(hFile);
   },,

Comment: GetLastError returns 5 ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED